# Get timeout with URLSession dataTask in Swift after restart app because retain cycle with delegate

Tags: swift, urlsession

I use the following code to make a HTTP requests with URLSession and dataTask, but sometimes it gives me timeouts.

I just use the URLSessionDelegate to bypass the Authentication Server Trust in one of our development servers that uses HTTPS, if I use urlSession without delegate.

This error is completely inconsistent. Sometimes it works perfect, sometimes not.

Is it possible to validate the HTTP Server with the "URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!" without using a delegate ?

```
func fetch(with url:String, completion: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    
    let request = URLSessionHelper.getRequestWithUrl(endpointUrl: url, httpMethod: HTTPMethod.get, jsonBodyData: nil)
    weak var session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionHelper.sessionConfiguration, delegate: SessionDelegate.shared, delegateQueue: nil)
    session!.dataTask(with: request,  completionHandler: {
        data, response, error in
        
        guard let data = data else {
            print("nil data")
            completion(.failure(NetworkError.timeout))
            return
        }
        
        if error != nil {
            print("nil error \(error!)")
            completion(.failure(error!))
        } else {
            print("success")
            completion(.success(data))
        }
        
    }).resume()        
}
```

This is my SessionDelegate class

```
class SessionDelegate:NSObject, URLSessionDelegate
{

static var shared: SessionDelegate = {
    let instance = SessionDelegate()
    return instance
}()

//private override init() {}
    
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {
    // usado para fazer o bypass na autenticação self-signed do certificado do servidor
    // We've got a URLAuthenticationChallenge - we simply trust the HTTPS server and we proceed
    print("start didReceive challenge 1")
    completionHandler(.useCredential, URLCredential(trust: challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust!))
}
```

EDIT 1

If I use

```
UrlSession.shared.dataTask
```

with a secondary data server(that uses HTTP, not HTTPS) instead of using

```
weak var session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionHelper.sessionConfiguration, delegate: SessionDelegate.shared, delegateQueue: nil
```

everything works fine. But our clients use the HTTPS server, because of that I need to figure out how to create a code that could be used with the HTTPS server without to be locked in the retain cycle that involves URLSession and the delegate.

EDIT 2

I modify the code:

```
let request = URLSessionHelper.getRequestWithUrl(endpointUrl: url, httpMethod: HTTPMethod.get, jsonBodyData: nil)
    weak var session = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionHelper.sessionConfiguration, delegate: SessionDelegate.shared, delegateQueue: nil)
    session!.dataTask(with: request,  completionHandler: {
        data, response, error in
        
        guard let data = data else {
            print("nil data")
            completion(.failure(NetworkError.timeout))
            session!.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
            return
        }
        
        if error != nil {
            print("nil error \(error!)")
            completion(.failure(error!))
            session!.finishTasksAndInvalidate() // invalidateAndCancel() or finishTasksAndInvalidate()
        } else {
            print("success")
            completion(.success(data))
            session!.finishTasksAndInvalidate()
        }
        
        
    }).resume()
```

but the problem still persists, if I restart the app and try to call URLSession, the problem appears for me.

If I use "invalidateAndCancel()" instead of "finishTasksAndInvalidate()", the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most classes that have a delegate, the delegate object is held weakly. `URLSession` is an exception to that. If you look at the `URLSession` docs, they say:

> **Important**: 
> The session object keeps a strong reference to the delegate until your app exits or explicitly invalidates the session. If you do not invalidate the session by calling the invalidateAndCancel() or finishTasksAndInvalidate() method, your app leaks memory until it exits.

So it sounds like your should call `invalidateAndCancel()` or `finishTasksAndInvalidate()`  once you are done with your session. That would cause the session to release it's delegate.

Comment: I edit my question and try to call invalidateAndCancel() in my first attempt and on my second attempt I try to call finishTasksAndInvalidate(). The behavior is the same.